# Unconfirmed transactions for a week

Tags: blockchain

I sent two transactions to the same place. I *think* they both show in blockchain, but they aren't at the intended address. After 48 hours, I got concerned and changed from Electrum to Bitcoin-Qt, sending my remaining coins to Bitcoin-Qt. That doesn't show in the blockchain as far as I can see. I included the default transaction fee each time.

After about a week, I'm still in the same state. I'll add transaction ID's when I get back to my mac. More info to follow. I checked answers to other questions but couldn't find a resolve or anything that seemed to fit my attempted exchanges.

Comment: Ok .... I have since discovered my transactions are not showing in blockchain (4 of). I show a balance in Electrum of 1.44 BTC but (-1.43 unconfirmed). I included a transaction fee in each and don't have a clue what's going on. When will they show as confirmed so I can try spend them again? What do I do?

Comment: One transaction I sent has trans ID 4fc11dfed692179f4105b9f258ea5d740cab458bcce9624eee05d0f6e41f1645 ...I sent 0.01 BTC somewhere as I realised I'd not sent enough. It says in blockchain I have an unspent amount of almost 1 whole BTC which adds up to the rest of the transactions that are pending without confirmations. Tx fee included each time. Everything else is as it is above. The address sent from is 1LCbjmRZ5LxjkSBtN4FDFPhgwieHmfkK8B .... Please help I am so lost. Reward for the solver. For real